# Apple access to SMB on Linux server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, server-message-block

Please help.  Looking for advice as to how best access files on Linux SMB server from Mac machines without running into the inability to use Mac spotlight search. Something like Acronis Files Connect which works on Windows servers but not Linux, would be great.  This an already setup Linux server with thousands of media files on there so not asking the question from a starting point or creation of the server, the server exists already and won't be easy to just change it to Windows etc.  I have limited knowledge of IT so please keep the answers in standard terms.

Many thanks in advance

Alan  FH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add an AFP service to your Linux server (e.g. netatalk) and connect your clients with that instead of SMB (AFAIK that's what this Acronis product does as well).

Plenty of guides should be available to help you with that.